# Why this() bracket are present in template literal

Tags: javascript

Hello I am following a Udemy course on java script and have a question about one line of the code

why he applied the bracket () in the template literal after the trophy emoji
`` console.log(`Dolphins win  (${avgDolphins} vs. ${avgKoalas})`) ``

this is the code and the instructions for the exercise.

1. Create an arrow function `calcAverage` to calculate the average of 3 scores
2. Use the function to calculate the average for both teams
3. Create a function `checkWinner` that takes the average score of each team as parameters (`avgDolhins` and `avgKoalas`), and then logs the winner to the console, together with the victory points, according to the rule above. Example: "Koalas win (30 vs. 13)".
4. Use the `checkWinner` function to determine the winner for both DATA 1 and DATA 2.
5. Ignore draws this time.

TEST DATA 1: Dolphins score 44, 23 and 71. Koalas score 65, 54 and 49
TEST DATA 2: Dolphins score 85, 54 and 41. Koalas score 23, 34 and 27

```js
const calcAverage = (a, b, c) => (a + b + c) / 3;
console.log(calcAverage(3, 4, 5));

// Test 1
let scoreDolphins = calcAverage(44, 23, 71);
let scoreKoalas = calcAverage(65, 54, 49);
console.log(scoreDolphins, scoreKoalas);

const checkWinner = function (avgDolphins, avgKoalas) {
  if (avgDolphins >= 2 * avgKoalas) {
    console.log(`Dolphins win  (${avgDolphins} vs. ${avgKoalas})`);
  } else if (avgKoalas >= 2 * avgDolphins) {
    console.log(`Koalas win  (${avgKoalas} vs. ${avgDolphins})`);
  } else {
    console.log('No team wins...');
  }
}
checkWinner(scoreDolphins, scoreKoalas);
```

Comment: The brackets do nothing, they're just semantically part of the string.

Comment: That is because the instructor wanted the result to have brackets. So it would look something like - "Dolphins win  (5 vs. 4)"

Answer (score 0):

It's just a part of the logged string, you will see a string like this on the console :   " Dolphins win (1 vs. 3)".

Comment: thanks for the answers, any idea why I got 4- on the question :(

Comment: @jakubklos, maybe it is unclear or not useful  question for others